# UILabels dont show unless there is text in them tableviewcell autolayout

Tags: autolayout

I have a tableview cell and im using the UIAutomaticDimensions functionality to make sure the tableview cell can size itself. The cell has 3 labels and an imageview as its contents. Now the problem is with the labels and their vertical constraints. unless there is text in the label the label will not show. It just overwrites the previous position of the label on top of it and makes the cell very very small. What i want to be able to do is always display all three labels so the height of the cell is always the same as another cell.

**How can i achieve showing the label even if there is no text in the label?**

*Heres an explination of the contents constraints.*

```
[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_prospect_avatar
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.contentView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:0.0f]];

[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_prospect_avatar
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self.contentView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                            multiplier:1.0f
                                                              constant:100.0f]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_prospect_avatar]|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_prospect_avatar)]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[_prospect_avatar][_full_name_label]-|"
                                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_prospect_avatar,_full_name_label)]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[_prospect_avatar][_phone_number_label]-|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_prospect_avatar,_phone_number_label)]];

[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[_prospect_avatar][_email_label]-|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_prospect_avatar,_email_label)]];

[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[_full_name_label][_email_label][_phone_number_label]-10-|"
                                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                           views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_full_name_label,_email_label,_phone_number_label)]];
```

Comment: Also i forgot to add. That if i just place a space in each label if the actual data of that label is nil, the lables stack on top of eachother fine. BUt i dont think thats the correct way to fix my problem

Comment: give all the label as height >= 20 or what you want with all the constraints. It will work.

Comment: Ahh ok i see what u mean i totally forgot about that. The greater than or equal to at least 20 points then it will always be greater than 20points. I should allow it to autosize itself correct?

Answer (score 1):

Mahesh Agrawala has the correct answer. In the vertical constraints for eah of the labels i have to add a greater than or less than value for the labels height. So for example what i previously had set for the constraints was

```
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[_full_name_label][_email_label][_phone_number_label]-10-|"
                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_full_name_label,_email_label,_phone_number_label)]];
```

WHen really the constraint should have looked like

```
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[_full_name_label(>=20)][_email_label(>=20)][_phone_number_label(>=20)]-10-|"
                                                                    options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading
                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                       views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_full_name_label,_email_label,_phone_number_label)]];
```

If you look at my new constraints **at the end of each label in the constraint i have added (>=20) right before the trailing ] this tells autolayout that i at least want this label to 20 points or greater in height**

There are numerous other ways to do this so this is not the only way to accomplish my task but in this circumstance it was the quickest.